# MySql Concat in "AS" name column

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.5

I need to concatenate a dynamic text with a fixed text in the name of the columns in a select.

I'm trying to run a command like this:

```
set @y = '2017';
SELECT 1 AS Concat('January ',@y);
```

But mysql returns me a syntax error in parentheses.

Trying only with the variable, I also have syntax error:

```
set @y = '2017';
SELECT 1 AS @y;
```

What would be the correct way to have the column name in function of a variable?

Thanks

Comment: You can use this only for values. For column names, you need to use: `$$`.

Comment: Where do I have to put it $$? @Soolie

Comment: Why do you want to use `AS`? Why not just `SELECT Concat('January ', @y);`?

Comment: @rednaw because I need the column name to be like Concat('January ', @y);  since the user will make queries going through the year that he wants

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to run select like this. You have to go dynamic

```
set @y = '2017';
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT 1 as January', @y); 

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql; 
EXECUTE stmt; 
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```